# I cant able to make the listview for response from json

Tags: listview, fetch, react-native, react-native-ios

**Below is my json response**

*This is my josn which having result object which having student_name ,where i need to display in my fetch method i am converting response to response.json()*

> 

```
 {
"code": "200",
"status": "Success",
"Msg": "No Details",

"results": {
    "student_name": "Prasanna",
    "roll_no": "1",
    "id": "8",
    "std_id": "A180001",
    "org_id": "2",
    "institute_id": "2",
    "class_id": "1",
    "section_id": "1",
    }
 }
```

**Then i am cloning**

```
this.setState({
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows( responseJson.results),
 })
```

**Then in my render method**

```
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}

    renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}

    renderRow={(rowData) =>

   <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'column'}} >

     <TouchableOpacity 
     onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, rowData.student_name)}>

     <Text style={styles.textViewContainer}>
       {'id = ' + rowData.student_name}
    </Text>

 </TouchableOpacity>

   </View>

    }
  />
```

**This is what i am getting in need to  display only name**

[image: This is what i am getting in need to show display name]

**I need to display only student_name**

Answer (score 0):

The `renderRow` prop accepts parameters a little unconventionally. Change

```
renderRow={(rowData)=>{}}
```

to

```
renderRow={({rowData})=>{}}
```

The extra set of curly brackets inside serves to unwrap the parameter